# 几 in declarative and interrogative sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, difference, pronunciation, spoken

几 has two meanings: "several" and "how many?" But I have no clear understanding of separation one from another. E.g.:

> 后面有几个人笑起来了. - *declarative*
>
> 你家有几口人? - *interrogative*

I know that the first sentence is declarative and the second one is interrogative but I don't know why. There is no difference in 几 usage here so why is the first sentence declarative?

> A few people laughed behind [us].
>
> **And not interrogative:** How many people laughed behind [us]?

"几个人" could be as well "a few people" and "how many people?", how to distinguish which one is used? (An example of interrogative sentence with "几个人" would be useful)

P.S.: please do not give explanation like "后面有几个人笑起来了." is declarative because "后面有多少人笑起来了?" is interrogative. I also can say that in the case "你家有几口人" is declarative ("There are some people in your family") because there is no "多少人".

---

Another example, you are speaking to a person and he says:

> 上海有几个火车站(。/？)

Only context can help you to understand whether it is a question or a declaration, right?

> *(on the street)*
>
> 请问, 上海有几个火车站(？) - *defenetely interrogative*

And:

> - 到火车站要10分钟, 不要着急。
>
> - 上海有几个火车站(。)我去上海南站, 到那儿要半个小时。 - *declarative*

Comment: users note that 呢 often occurs at the end of certain types of interrogative sentences (alternative questions or those with interrogative pronouns (e.g. 几）），as a test search web with 几  呢：  
孩子移民的黄金时间是几岁呢？会计账户分为几类呢？会计账户分为几类呢？

Answer (score 3):

I think all the sentences with 几 above can turn into interrogative sentences. For example:

> 后面有几个人笑起来了?
>
> 你家有几口人?
>
> 上海有几个火车站?

In the mainland mandarin, we usually put 好 in front of 几 in the declarative sentence to indicate that there are more than one. For example:

> 后面有(好)几个人笑起来了。// 好 can be omitted without changing the meaning.
>
> 你家有好几口人。// 好 can not be omitted
>
> 上海有好几个火车站。// 好 can not be omitted

With 好，you can differentiate if it's a declarative or interrogative sentence.  In some sentences (like the first one above), 好 is omissible. You'd better not omit 好 in the sentence 2 and 3, otherwise they would sound like interrogative sentences.

Answer (score 2):

### There is a way for distinction: intonation

As stated by the OP, the meaning is clear once we know whether the sentence is *declarative* or a *question*. The key point about identifying the sentence type in a conversation, other than the context, is intonation.

**Example:**

I asked a friend who is a native speaker of mandarin (from Shanghai) to pronounce the following sentences:

1. 那里有几个人? (How many people is there?)

https://soundcloud.com/user-169031882/k0n1e11edws0?in=user-169031882/sets/chinese-intonation-difference

2. 那里有几个人. (There are a few people.)

https://soundcloud.com/user-169031882/kc4x4i2w6psc?in=user-169031882/sets/chinese-intonation-difference

He argued in the **interrogative** sentence he stressed the question word **几**, while in the **declarative** sentence, he stressed the object **人**.

---

### General discussion: declarative vs question intonation

Apart from *lexical tones*, mandarin chinese like most languages has a *sentence intonation*. Sentence intonation can be thought of the overlaying tune of the sentence, with fluctuations given by the lexical tones [1]. Surprisingly, the study of sentence intonation and its interaction with the lexical tones is a complex topic, which is still active in linguistics research.

*Wh-words*, the interrogative words such as *shénme* 什么, *shéi* 谁 or *jǐ* 几 can sometimes be ambiguous between a declarative and question interpretation. This is precisely the topic of study of an article from last month [2]. Considering sentences like the example I gave above for wh-words, they studied the intonation of the interrogative vs declarative sentences, and found the following results:

- Questions are spoken faster than declarations.
- Questions have more 'focus' in the wh-words (as my friend said): with a longer duration, a steep pitch rise and a stronger volume change (what is called intensity range).
- Questions usually maintain the pitch raised at the wh-word until the end of the sentence.
- Declarations have more focus at the verb and wh-words are instead largely suppressed with an almost flat pitch, a short duration and a small volume change.

[1] Crosswhite, K. M., & McDonough, J. (2000). Comparison of intonation patters in Mandarine and English for a particular Speaker. University of Rochester Working Papers in the Language Science, 1, 24-55.

[2] Yang, Y., Gryllia, S., & Cheng, L. L. S. (2020). Wh-question or wh-declarative? Prosody makes the difference. Speech Communication, 118, 21-32 (see [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167639319301244)).

Comment: I asked myself this question a while ago and asked some native speakers to read two sentences aloud. They were: 1) 出去了几个人。2)出去了几个人？I came to similar conclusions as in this answer. However I didn't notice a difference in speed. For the 'focus' observation (points #2, #4 in the answer) I think it could be useful to think of it as the neutral tone (轻声) being used for the "declarative" case, and not being used in the "question" case.

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler Actually you are right, the difference in speed they found in the article is not much, around 1.5% of the duration. For a sentence of 12 syllables, the declarative sentence took around 2,05 s and the question around 2,02 s. If you check the article they also have very nice plots, they were quite informative (though by copyright reasons I couldn't use them on the answer).

Answer (score 1):

'**几**' in '你家有**几**个人?' means '**几多**个人'(**how many** people?)

'**几**' in '后面有**几**个人笑起来了' just means '**few**'

几 is 'declarative' (few/ several) when the sentence ends with a period; and it is 'interrogative' (how many) when the sentence ends with a question mark

去了几次. (went there a few times.)

去了几次? (went there how many times?)

'interrogative' sentence  is always in question form, end with a question mark, including rhetorical question.

Comment: What about speach? No one says "后面有几个人笑起来了问号"

Comment: It should be "后面有几(多)个人笑起来了?"  Some people might choose to omit  '多' but that make it less colloquial and more literary. Let me give you a literary sentence example , '知己有几(多个)人?' should always ends with a question mark. and (多个) is always omitted

Comment: wikipedia：the concept of modern standard punctuation was adapted in the written language during the 20th century from Western punctuation marks，also Chinese subtitles have none

Comment: Would it be safe to say that in ambiguous situations you can add clarity either by including '?' or 多?

Comment: 知己有几多个人 sounds very odd to my ear. I'd say 知己有几(个)人.

Comment: @TangHo When your two sample sentences (1: “去了几次。”; 2: “去了几次？”) are spoken aloud, should there be an difference in pronunciation? I wouldn’t be surprised if the answer to this is something along the lines of: “Yes. in ‘去了几次。’, the 几 is unstressed/has neutral tone; in ‘去了几次?’, the 几 has some degree of stress/has third tone”. (Seee https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Chinese_phonology#Full_and_weak_syllables and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Chinese_phonology#Stress,_rhythm_and_intonation for some discussion of stress and neutral tone - it seems to be a complex topic.)